# Seismic effects resulting from tidal action on Ganymede and Europa

Tags: gravity, europa, seismology

What kind of seismic activity is going to be generated by the tidal forces exerted on these two moon's ice sheets by Jupiter? Would it be a great enough differential in the ice sheets to preclude livable structures being built below the surface of the ice sheet?

Comment: Do you only want facts, or are educated guesses welcome as well?

Comment: As long as its not pureley opinion Im not too picky. All I can find anywhere else on the net is a vague "theres probably seismic activity." In an orbit around jupiter youd think tidally generated seismic effects would be a lot more pronounced than "some."

Comment: What shielding information?

Comment: Informative, but Im not asking about radiation, Im interested in siesmic activity generated by tidal forces.

Comment: Huh, you're right, inspiration for the question is quite irrelevant, didn't notice that. I'll edit accordingly.